# KML to SHP layer is still missing the added fields Running without error

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, arcgis-pro, kml

This is the script that will run without the running without line 28 that causes the error but is not adding the fields from the html field.  I think I am missing something at 28 but when I had the recommended code I get error that it is not a valid command

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [5]:
Line 28:    update_layer = arcpy.mp.ListLayer(database + '\\' + FC)

AttributeError: module 'arcpy.mp' has no attribute 'ListLayer'
```

```
import arcpy, os

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
   
input_parameter = r'c:\GIS_Working\zoning.kmz'
   
direct = os.path.dirname(input_parameter)
arcpy.conversion.KMLToLayer(input_parameter, direct)
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

database = input_parameter[:-3] + 'gdb'
dataset = database + '\Placemarks'

arcpy.env.workspace = dataset
GCS_List = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
coord_sys = arcpy.SpatialReference('NAD 1983 StatePlane California V FIPS 0405 (US Feet)')
e_count = 0

for FC in GCS_List:
    arcpy.Project_management(FC, database + '\\' + FC + '_Proj', coord_sys)

    arcpy.env.workspace = database    
UTM_List = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

keep_fields = ['OID', 'Shape', 'SHAPE', 'Name', 'FolderPath', 'SymbolID', 'PopupInfo', 'Shape_Length', 'Shape_Area',]
  
for FC in UTM_List:
    update_layer = arcpy.mp.ListLayers(database + '\\' + FC)
    arcpy.mp.AddLayer(df, update_layer) 
   
SC = arcpy.SearchCursor(FC)

for row in SC:
    pop_string = row.getValue("PopupInfo")
    pop_array = pop_string.split("<")
    fields_array = []
    names_array = []
            
for tag in pop_array:
    if "td>" in tag and "/td>" not in tag:
        fields_array.append(segment)
    break

for fields in arcpy.ListFields(FC):
    if fields.name not in keep_fields:
        arcpy.DeleteField_management(FC,fields.name)
    
del fields_array[:2]

for x in range(0,len(fields_array)):
    fields_array[x]=fields_array[x].replace("td>","")
    if x%2 == 0 and fields_array[x] not in keep_fields:
        names_array.append(fields_array[x])
        arcpy.AddField_management(FC, fields_array[x], "TEXT")

names_array.append("PopupInfo")

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(FC,names_array) as UC:
    for row in UC:
        pop_string = row[-1]
        pop_array = pop_string.split("<")
        fields_array = []
        values_array = []
            
    for segment in pop_array:
        if "td>" in segment and "/td>" not in segment:
            fields_array.append(segment)

del fields_array[:2]

for x in range(0,len(fields_array)):
    if x%2!=0:
        if fields_array[x-1] not in keep_fields:
            fields_array[x]=fields_array[x].replace("td>","")
            values_array.append(fields_array[x])

for y in range(0,len(values_array)):
    try:
        row[y] = values_array[y]
       
    except IndexError:
            e_count = e_count + 1
     
aprx.save()
```

Comment: `arcpy.mapping` (ArcMap) works differently to `arcpy.mp` (Pro) - [many of the list functions have moved](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/migratingfrom10xarcpymapping.htm#:~:text=into%20a%20project.-,Many%20of%20the%20list%20functions%20have%20moved,-Many%20of%20the). But neither the ArcMap or Pro `ListLayers` method works for featureclasses in a workspace, they only work for `Layers` in a map.

Comment: There is a field that comes over with an HTML string and I want to strip that out into fields with the data from the html. The script was from and old ArcMap/Python 2 script I found on here. It is copying the layer but not adding the fields and data to the field.

Comment: @SonofaBeach nope, `ListLayers` is a [method of a `Map` object](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/migratingfrom10xarcpymapping.htm#:~:text=lyr%20in%20m.-,listLayers,-()%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20lyr), not a top level `arcpy.mp` function.

Comment: How do I get the html out of the field and into new fields?

Comment: @user2856 so that's a "yes" AND a "no".  YES, it should have an "s" at the end of it (ie, ".ListLayers()", NOT ".ListLayer()", but NO, it is not "arcpy.mp.ListLayers()", nor "arcpy.mp.ListLayer()".

Comment: @SonofaBeach yep :)

Comment: SO what is the correct line to get the html out of that field into new fields?

Comment: What do I put in place of the ListLayers
for FC in GCS_List:
    arcpy.Project_management(FC, database + '\\' + FC + '_Proj', coord_sys)

arcpy.env.workspace = database    
UTM_List = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
df = aprx.listMaps()[0]